# Does the order of locations change when making a voronoi map with leaft and sf?

Tags: r, leaflet, r-sf, voronoi, rnaturalearth

I am making a voronoi map in R using the packages leaflet and sf as follows:

```
library(leaflet)
library(sf)
library(rnaturalearth)
library(rnaturalearthdata)

long   <- c(4.35556 ,  5.83745,  4.63683 ,  6.06389,  6.41111,  5.639722)
lat    <- c(52.00667, 53.09456, 52.38084 , 52.475  , 52.15917, 53.440278)
labs   <- c("Delft" , "Grouw" , "Haarlem", "Hattem", "Lochem", "Hollum" )
colors <- c("red"   , "orange", "yellow" , "green" , "blue"  , "purple" )

df <- data.frame(ID = labs, X = long, Y = lat)
points <- st_geometry(st_as_sf(df, coords = c("X", "Y")))
points <- st_union(points)

NL <- ne_countries(country = c('netherlands'), scale = 'medium', returnclass = 'sf')

polys <- points       %>% 
  st_voronoi()        %>%
  st_cast()           %>%
  st_set_crs(., 4326) %>%
  st_intersection(y = NL)

leaflet() %>%
addProviderTiles(providers$OpenStreetMap.Mapnik) %>%
addPolygons     (data        = polys,
                 fillColor   = colors,
                 fillOpacity = 1,
                 weight      = 0.5, 
                 color       = "black") %>%
addCircleMarkers(lng         = long,
                 lat         = lat,
                 label       = labs, 
                 color       = "black",
                 radius      = 5,
                 weight      = 1,
                 fill        = TRUE,
                 fillColor   = colors,
                 fillOpacity = 1)
```

In the resulting map the colors of the dots are correct, but the colors of the polygons are not correct. I guess something has changed in order of the locations in 'polys', but I am puzzled about this. Any suggestions how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`st_voronoi()` indeed appears not to keep the order of input points in the resulting polygons. You may use `st_intersects()` to find out which polygon belongs to which point and reorder `polys` accordingly.

First store a copy of `points` before applying `st_union()` and set them the same CRS as `polys` will have, so that`st_intersects()` works later on. I.e., insert this before the `points <- st_union(points)` line:

```r
points0 <- st_set_crs(points, 4326)
```

Then, after creating `polys`, reorder them like this:

```r
polys <- polys[unlist(st_intersects(points0, polys))]
```

If some point is located outside the area of Netherlands (as provided by `ne_countries()`) the matching of points to polygons has to be done before intersecting of `polys` and `NL`. So in the original code the `polys <- points...` will be replaced with:

```r
polys <- points       %>% 
  st_voronoi()        %>%
  st_cast()           %>%
  st_set_crs(., 4326) 
polys <- polys[unlist(st_intersects(points0, polys))]
polys <- st_intersection(polys, NL)
```

Comment: The help file for `st_voronoi` has this in its examples and has saved me several times....

Comment: @Spacedman Oh, indeed! And switching polygons and points in `st_intersect()` means it is not necessary to use `order` afterwards and makes things easier. Hadn't thought of that... Thanks!

Comment: I found  the suggestions of Robert Hacken very helpful, but unfortunately it goes wrong again when not all locations are found in the same polygon. For example when adding Hollum (found on a island in the North) with lat=53.440278 and long=5.639722.

Comment: Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Yes, there is, see the end of my updated answer. The problem was that the island point was outside the area of Netherlands returned by `ne_countries()`, so matching by `st_intersection()` was not succesful.